# display message of the day in time interval, let's say maybe every one hour

Tags: etc, motd

I am trying to execute the message in a specific time interval for every user that logs in to their root

Comment: duplicate of "how do i really annoy all logged in users because my message is way more important than their work"?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this:

- use [`wall`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wall.1.html) to broadcast a message to logged-in users.  This has the drawback that it is sent even if they are editing a file.  You can schedule that using [`cron`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html), e.g., this entry in **`root`**'s [crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html):

  `* 0 * * * wall /etc/motd`
- if they happen to be using `bash` (and if you have control over their configuration), the bash prompt can execute shell functions via [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html).